# Firebase .queryStarting not working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This just isn't returning anything even though there are messages with timestamps above this one.

Code not properly sorting:

```
let messagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("all-messages").child(messageId).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: 1511130644)
```

Full code of Firebase calls:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUserUid).child("timestampOfLastVisit").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        timestamp = snapshot.value as! NSNumber

        groupMessagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("groups").child(groupId).child("messages")
        groupMessagesRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if self.sentMessage {
                let messageId = snapshot.key

                let messagesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("all-messages").child(messageId).queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryStarting(atValue: 1511130644)
                messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in ...
```

Relevant Firebase JSON (fake data obviously):

```
{
  "all-messages" : {
    "-KzLOuvEdLWy7vfc2XsT" : {
      "fromId" : "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1",
      "groupId" : "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL",
      "isStarred" : true,
      "text" : "This should show",
      "timestamp" : 1511130640
    },
    "-KzLOw5OxZ4P_I0d70gZ" : {
      "fromId" : "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1",
      "groupId" : "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL",
      "isStarred" : false,
      "text" : "And so should this",
      "timestamp" : 1511130644
    },
    "-KzLS4uwDtpW6wHNxrmc" : {
      "fromId" : "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1",
      "groupId" : "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL",
      "isStarred" : false,
      "text" : "1",
      "timestamp" : 1511131471
    },
    "-KzLS5FvASnj_ky4WQkd" : {
      "fromId" : "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1",
      "groupId" : "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL",
      "isStarred" : false,
      "text" : "2",
      "timestamp" : 1511131472
    }
  },
  "groups" : {
    "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL" : {
      "groupCreator" : "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1",
      "groupDescription" : "Group",
      "groupImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/groupchat1-a1da3.appspot.com/o/group_profile_images%2FA4DDA286-E7A3-4F96-ABF0-5717F4029C33.png?alt=media&token=6ad79728-74fd-405f-abbf-247dae4684b5",
      "groupMemberOneSignalIds" : {
        "5905a2f5-dfa3-46d7-964f-596bd2f2004a" : true,
        "67b9cb2a-6583-45b4-9fed-93cf333e9ca4" : true,
        "a1bf9ed9-0959-4c88-974b-5a829c1cdcc9" : true,
        "f2fb84b9-86af-40e7-8667-989a95b2e282" : true
      },
      "groupMembers" : {
        "3lQiuzudFGW51UwQ4Mseu8aOxyu2" : true,
        "JF7SCe3VUcWJi1ujumx0VpyaG5s1" : true,
        "YEbVehx0cqTvNaKrJTcs5GnRLGM2" : true,
        "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1" : true
      },
      "groupName" : "1",
      "groupTags" : {
        "-Kxk3kHxMuWQHEsaWN5k" : "1",
        "-Kxk3kHyMB2OL5pNAfW1" : "1",
        "-Kxk3kHyMB2OL5pNAfW2" : "1"
      },
      "messages" : {
        "-KzLOuvEdLWy7vfc2XsT" : 1,
        "-KzLOw5OxZ4P_I0d70gZ" : 1,
        "-KzLS4uwDtpW6wHNxrmc" : 1,
        "-KzLS5FvASnj_ky4WQkd" : 1
      },
      "starredMessages" : {
        "-KzLOuvEdLWy7vfc2XsT" : 1511204335
      }
    },
    "-Kxn_yTAZvkPls-_s8He" : {
      "groupCreator" : "JF7SCe3VUcWJi1ujumx0VpyaG5s1",
      "groupDescription" : "Group 3",
      "groupImageUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/groupchat1-a1da3.appspot.com/o/group_profile_images%2FD2C68A8F-33DC-43C6-8C99-762315760208.png?alt=media&token=aae87339-877e-484e-a0e1-a2e13455176c",
      "groupName" : "Group 3",
      "groupTags" : {
        "-Kxn_ygovR7mQIph3WiC" : "1",
        "-Kxn_ygovR7mQIph3WiD" : "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "JF7SCe3VUcWJi1ujumx0VpyaG5s1" : {
      "email" : "Madi@gmail.com",
      "groups" : {
        "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL" : true,
        "-Kxk3n99i43MYECm1Ix8" : true,
        "-KxuBPAPBIcROMEtNujW" : true,
        "-KxuET1pZGg2x_aJvRkU" : true
      },
      "profileImageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/groupchat1-a1da3.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2F246CA55C-446D-4A24-8BE6-8B5B9C0F27AF.png?alt=media&token=47022ccd-1c92-460a-8630-e74a0d68bc4a",
      "searchUsername" : "madi",
      "timestampOfLastVisit" : 1511241228,
      "username" : "Madi"
    },
    "zhBZyAVGvAMZWi4QhvKDu7qb3Qr1" : {
      "email" : "Connor@gmail.com",
      "groups" : {
        "-Kxk3kA9I8OEvNmFcavL" : true,
        "-Kxk3n99i43MYECm1Ix8" : true
      },
      "profileImageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/groupchat1-a1da3.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2FBDC4020E-9F54-4F80-A4DC-668804215DE3.png?alt=media&token=ec2c8875-e6e4-40d5-8c07-3d743bf4ea16",
      "searchUsername" : "connor",
      "timestampOfLastVisit" : 1511205356,
      "username" : "Connor"
    }
  }
}
```

What print(snapshot) prints:

```
Snap (-KzLOw5OxZ4P_I0d70gZ) <null>
```

print(messageRef):

```
(/all-messages/-KzLOw5OxZ4P_I0d70gZ {
    i = timestamp;
    sp = 1511130644;
})
```

Comment: This question is kind of all over the place; the nodes referenced in the code are not shown in the link, *all-messages*, *timestampOfLastVisit*, *group* etc. In general it's best to include a snippet of your Firebase structure as TEXT (Firebase console->Export JSON) and also include code snippets that addresses those specific nodes as if a node is being referenced that doesn't exist, your results would be no found nodes. Maybe indicating what messagesRef actually references i.e. print(messagesRef) would help. If you can update your question, we can take a look and perhaps find the issue.

Comment: Oh. and you are missing a .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp") in the last query so Firebase knows which node you are querying on.

Comment: @Jay Updated post. It works perfectly if I remove the .queryStarting(atValue:), but it loads all of the messages. However, I want to include .queryStarting(atValue:) so I am loading in only the messages that have been sent since the users last visit. However that causes the snapshot value to be null and it still queries all of the messages, not just the ones after that timestamp. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to create a query that will return the node that has a particular time stamp.

The problem is your code is querying one level too deep. In other words, you need to let Firebase iterate over the child nodes of all-messages until it finds one that has a child timestamp of 1511130644. So it will need to iterate over

```
msg_0
msg_1
msg_2
```

etc.

Your code is trying to be too specific and you are telling it to look at a particular message Id for the data in the query - which doesn't make sense as if you know the exact path, you wouldn't need to query!

This is a common misunderstanding - just remember that queries need to be provided the parent node and then the child node of what you are querying for as it will then iterate over the child_nodes just underneath the parent.

```
parent_node
  child_node
     child_node_of_what_you_are_querying
  child_node
     child_node_of_what_you_are_querying
```

Here is code to query for a certain time stamp - note the messageId is not needed

```
//self.ref is the firebase ref
let messagesRef = self.ref.child("all-messages").queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
                                                .queryStarting(atValue: 1511130644)
messagesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.hasChildren() {
        print("got snap with children")
    } else {
        print("no snap found")
    }
})
```

If you already know the specific path you can observe it directly. So if you want to print the timestamp for a certain message

```
let thisMsgRef = self.ref.child("all-messages").child(messageId)
let thisTimestampRef = thisMsgRef.child("timestamp")
thisTimestampRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    print(snap.value) //prints the timestamp
}
```

Comment: Awesome Jay! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `queryStartingAtValue()` is only used to disambiguate between items that match the first argument. To filter by `timestamp` you should call `queryOrderedByChild("timestamp")`:

```
let messagesRef = 
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("all-messages").child(messageId)
             .queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp")
             .queryStarting(atValue: 1511130644)
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that as well, it just happened that I was trying to include the second argument at the time I pasted it over. Still not working. In fact, I can't even get it to work if I use .queryEqual(toValue:) and just pass a hard-coded value in. I can get it to work if I do the sorting on a node with only one child and observing .childAdded instead of .value

Comment: I added the full Firebase code I am trying to use that is causing issues